# In Proverbs 8:28, what are "the fountains of the deep"?

Tags: proverbs

Proverbs 8-22-28 (NIV)

> 22 “The LORD brought me forth as the first of his works,[a][b]
>       before his deeds of old;
>   23 I was formed long ages ago,
>       at the very beginning, when the world came to be.
>   24 When there were no watery depths, I was given birth,
>       when there were no springs overflowing with water;
>   25 before the mountains were settled in place,
>       before the hills, I was given birth,
>   26 before he made the world or its fields
>       or any of the dust of the earth.
>   27 I was there when he set the heavens in place,
>       when he marked out the horizon on the face of the deep,
>   28 when he established the clouds above and fixed
>   securely **the fountains of the deep**...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Genesis 1 describes a preexistent bottomless chaotic ocean that is tamed by the LORD by causing the dry (and in the Middle East, we are talking very dry) land to be raised up from the bottomless sea and placed on mysterious foundations. God doesn't create, he orders preexistent material. Even light was pulled from the darkness.

Other cultures, [also?] influenced by Thales, wondered how the dry land could be supported in a bottomless ocean, and hypothesized that the dry land must be located on the back of giant turtles, endlessly swimming. Problem solved.

The old joke, "What supports the turtle?" answered by "It is supported by another turtle" and under that? "It's turtles all the way down [to infinity]" misses the point. A swimming turtle doesn't need another turtle under it. The ancients may have been working with bad presuppositions, but they weren't just plain stupid.

So in the biblical view, the ordered "world" that God created was not created *ex nihilo* but rather *ex hudatos":

> [2Pe 3:5 NASB20] [5] For when they maintain this, it escapes their notice that by the word of God [the] heavens existed long ago **and [the] earth was formed out of water and by water,**

> [Psa 24:1-2 WEB] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUAPr.jpg) A Psalm of David. The earth [is] the LORD'S, and the fullness thereof; the world, and they that dwell therein. **[2] For he hath founded it upon the seas, and established it upon the floods.**

> [Psa 75:3 NASB20] [3] "The earth and all who inhabit it are unsteady; It is I who have firmly set its pillars. Selah

God is seen as the Great Tamer:

> [Psa 74:13 NASB20] [13] You divided the sea by Your strength; You broke the heads of the sea monsters in the waters.

> [Psa 77:16 NASB20] [16] The waters saw You, God; The waters saw You, they were in anguish; The ocean depths also trembled.

> [Psa 93:4 NASB20] [4] More than the sounds of many waters, [Than] the mighty breakers of the sea, The LORD on high is mighty.

He is greater than the gods of chaos:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_gods

The "skies" are described as a giant reservoir of rain water, and the underside is lined with the sun, moon and stars, which are like a tapestry:

> [Heb 1:10-12 NIV] [10] He also says, "In the beginning, Lord, **you laid the foundations of the earth,** and the heavens are the **work of your hands.** [11] They will perish, but you remain; they will all wear out like a garment. **[12] You will roll them up like a robe; like a garment they will be changed.** But you remain the same, and your years will never end."

God's house is set on pilings in the midst of the reservoir:

[Psa 104:3 NASB20] **[3] He lays the beams of His upper chambers in the waters;** He makes the clouds His chariot; He walks on the wings of the wind;

[image: Houses on pilings]

Floods return the world to an unordered state:

> [2Pe 3:6 NKJV] [6] by which the world [that] then existed perished, being flooded with water.

Back to the question:

This is from the Jewish Encyclopedia, and I think it is accurate:

> FOUNTAIN (Hebr. ):
> By: Emil G. Hirsch, Frants Buhl
> A natural spring of water. Although Palestine as a whole is scantily supplied with water, it has a number of fountains. These often spring up in the hollows of cliffs; but sometimes wells have been dug. The Old Testament makes no sharp distinction between artificial wells and springs. Among the best-known fountains are the sources of the Jordan near Banias and Tell al-Ḳaḍi (Dan), the sources of the Gihon (St. Mary's Well) near Jerusalem, the Harod (Goliath) fountains in the valley leading from the plain of Jezreel to Scythopolis, and those near Nazareth. Numerous villages and towns have been named after the fountains which gave rise to the settlements, e.g., En-dor, En-gannim, En-gedi, Enshemesh, En-rimmon, and En-hazor.

https://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/6256-fountain

The fountains of the deep then are the many springs of the Hebrew world, which were amplified, along with the waters from the heavenly reservoir returned the world to an unordered state.

Note: None of this is actual factual. The sun moon and stars are not   under the reservoir of rain water.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Genesis 7:11 - the account of the flood says that not only did it rain, but the fountains of the deep burst forth. Water came from below the earth's crust as well as from the sky. The proverbs passage tells us that God was the one who fixed them, Genesis tells us that God let the waters loose.

It would be reasonable to assume that these manifested themselves in the form of underwater volcanoes - fissures in the earth's crust that resulted in the water below rising to cause the flood.

Answer (score 1):

We have hot water springs as evidence for underground waters... There are entire rivers and aquifers under ground. If you look at google maps you can actually see the fault lines under the sea - the most famous would be the Marianas Trench

Be blessed with love and joy and peace !!

Comment: Welcome to BHSE! Please make sure you take our [tour]. Re: Questions and answers, we'd like to see Biblical text to analyze. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer that may be a bit too science based for some. It is just a theory. The flood is not long after an ice age. Also, it is my understanding that sea levels were over 100 feet lower in the past. Ice depths were at least higher than Half Dome in Yosemite Valley at some point in time and are reported to have carved out the Great Lakes! If you imagine this Antarctic like ice sheet beginning to retreat, the lower ocean levels and a catastrophic flood can both be envisioned. A gigantic glacial lake could have broken loose and drained into a sea, like the Mediterranean for example, and it's water level would rise quickly, from it's "depth". The flood, or floods would not technically be global, but the "whole world" in the Fertile Crecent wasn't global, and furthermore, everyone thought the earth was flat! If I think the world is flat, and there's water is as far as I can see, that's a global flood in my view, even if it is not. (also, earth can mean just "dry land", not a round earth, which was unknowable at that time) I personally think observational science and spiritual truth agree, and when it does not, our understanding of one, or both, is lacking! If science wouldn't have proven the sun isn't a deity, most of the earth would still be worshiping it! We didn't even know women had "seed" until shockingly recently, and it was stated plainly 4000 years ago in Genesis. I'm confident that both God's creation and God's words are true. Just my opinion, though.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on both asking and answering questions.

Answer (score 0):

Reflecting upon Ps. 42:7, 'the deep calls to the deep' as you stated Gen. 7:11 'the fountains of the deep burst forth', this reminded me so much of the work of the Holy Spirit in the lives of His creation.  The woman at the well in John 4:37, 38, the filling of the Holy Spirit in the hearts and lives of His creation when received and released is like the fountains of the deep bursting forth.  If anyone thirsts let him come to Yeshua, and let him who believes in Me drink as the scriptures say, 'out of his innermost shall flow rivers of living water' Shalom

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Science says that the Gulf of Mexico was created by an impact from space. I can imagine that such a catastrophe would throw a lot of dust into the air, and the resulting fire would add even more, and the water surrounding the impact would boil and enter the atmosphere, and affect the climate world wide.

On top of that, such an impact could cause a huge ripple in the earth, causing volcanoes to erupt, adding more dust to the atmosphere, and underwater reservoirs to suddenly gush up through cracks in the earth.

Science today admits they dont know how much water is underground.  Can you imagine if a portion of what we see today in our oceans just started gushing out of the earth,  the effect it would have not only on dry land but on the settlement of the the earth afterward?

There may have been even a tsunami effect as well.  I see videos of recent tsunamis, and most don't show a huge wall of water crashing down, but just water comes in and keeps rising and rising and rising.

I believe the fountains of the deep, floods that covered mountains, and 40 days of rain were real observations, not just a local flood.  If it were local, the writers would have used different words.

Also, in reference to the statement of how dry the near east is, it used to be covered in vegetation (cedars of Lebanon) but due to bad farming techniques the land was irreversibly changed to what you see today.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I’d like to believe the fountain of the deep in Genesis 7:11 is God talking about Himself. If He says in Psalm 42:7a deep calleth unto deep at the noise of thy waterspouts. I believe He is referring to Himself, He is the creator, and the only one who could have had waters burst forth from Himself. He is a mysterious God, and rather than arguing mysteries, I’d live them be, and rest on the fact that He who created the world without seen foundations and pillars, will be the only one to answer. Just as He says, He that dwells in the secret place. He obviously is the secret place, so if He says fountains of the deep, He’s referring to Himself.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).